# training accuracy greater than validation accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, accuracy, overfitting

The problem that I'm facing is that the training accuracy of my model is way higher than the validation accuracy, were talking about an approximate value of `0.2`. And I can't understand why, yet I'm still a newbie when it comes to this so bear with me, please.

The data comes from two datasets which were created using `f.data.Dataset`, one for training another for validation since that's how the dataset had his folder layout.

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(.1),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss="categorical_crossentropy",
            metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, epochs=10, validation_data=test_ds, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS)
```

```
Train for 163.0 steps, validate for 20.0 steps
Epoch 1/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 21ms/step - loss: 3.9965 - accuracy: 0.8468 - val_loss: 0.3582 - val_accuracy: 0.8406
Epoch 2/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3197 - accuracy: 0.8930 - val_loss: 0.5207 - val_accuracy: 0.7641
Epoch 3/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.2009 - accuracy: 0.9191 - val_loss: 0.4350 - val_accuracy: 0.8062
Epoch 4/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.1815 - accuracy: 0.9270 - val_loss: 0.5521 - val_accuracy: 0.7516
Epoch 5/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.2122 - accuracy: 0.8986 - val_loss: 0.9616 - val_accuracy: 0.7156
Epoch 6/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.2405 - accuracy: 0.9082 - val_loss: 1.2039 - val_accuracy: 0.7109
Epoch 7/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.2013 - accuracy: 0.9183 - val_loss: 0.7242 - val_accuracy: 0.6406
Epoch 8/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.2055 - accuracy: 0.9176 - val_loss: 0.4830 - val_accuracy: 0.6891
Epoch 9/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.1901 - accuracy: 0.9250 - val_loss: 0.3925 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
Epoch 10/10
163/163 [==============================] - 3s 19ms/step - loss: 0.1861 - accuracy: 0.9202 - val_loss: 0.5492 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
```

Could anyone explain to me please what could cause this big gap in between accuracy and val_accuracy, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your model is clearly overfitting. You should use higher dropout value like 0.5 .For better generalization use deep models. And you can also use early stopping so that your model stops training before significantly overfitting.

Comment: I gave it a run with a dropout of 0.5 and early stop patience of 3 now the accuracy dropped significantly, from approx. 95 to 80. do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yes train accuracy will surely decrease. Training a model is not all about gaining higher accuracy in train set but in validation set. So train your model as long as your validation score increases. Or otherwise use different data augmentation , regularizer technique to improve both train and val score.

Comment: I know this might appeal silly to you, but I'm still a newbie when it comes to this. by suggesting to keep training are you referring to increasing the number of epochs?

Comment: Yes i am referring to give as many epoch as possible until your val score stop to increase